# median of column with awk

Tags: bash, sed, awk, median

How can I use AWK to compute the median of a column of numerical data?

I can think of a simple algorithm but I can't seem to program it:

What I have so far is:

```
sort | awk 'END{print NR}'
```

And this gives me the number of elements in the column. I'd like to use this to print a certain row `(NR/2)`. If `NR/2` is not an integer, then I round up to the nearest integer and that is the median, otherwise I take the average of `(NR/2)+1` and `(NR/2)-1`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This `awk` program assumes one column of numerically sorted data:

```
#/usr/bin/env awk
{
    count[NR] = $1;
}
END {
    if (NR % 2) {
        print count[(NR + 1) / 2];
    } else {
        print (count[(NR / 2)] + count[(NR / 2) + 1]) / 2.0;
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
sort -n data_file | awk -f median.awk
```

Comment: You can also use `asort` inside awk to sort the array.

Comment: @Vatine: Indeed you can. @Nick said he was using `sort` anyway, so I kept it simple.

Comment: @Vatine asort() is GNU-awk specific and would make the code a bit more complicated.

Comment: The `NR % 2` case is wrong, you need to subtract one from the index. For instance, if `NR = 3`, `count[1]` should be printed, but `(3 + 1) / 2 = 2`.

Comment: @RuudvA: That would be true were the the array zero-based but the first time `count[NR] = $1;` is called `NR == 1`. I believe this code to be correct (but, nearly five years later, I don't like `count` as a variable name).

Comment: I'm finding that `cat data_file | awk -f median.awk` (i.e., with no call to `sort`) is working, even though my data_file contains unsorted rows of integers. Why do you say the script assumes numerically-sorted data? I get an answer of '4' when my data_file contains .

Comment: Was having trouble with the formatting and now I'm blocked from editing my comment because 5 minutes have passed. Was going to say that my data_file contains  (as rows) these numbers: [12  3   4   4   1   4   4   2   4   5   6].

Comment: @Kevin: It's nice to be reminded of an answer I wrote six years ago! You get the right answer by luck with your input because there are 11 values and 4 is the value at position 6. Were your file to be ordered thus: [4
4
4
4
1
12
2
3
5
6
4], you'd get a very different result. See 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Medians_for_samples for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That's a subtle error for someone who isn't fully conversant with awk syntax, but I think I see how that works now. Cheers.

Comment: I've compared performance and sort -kn3 is considerably faster than awk '{print $0|"sort -nk3 "}'  (14 seconds compared with 66 seconds for a file with 1 million rows and 3 columns). Sorting before computing the median is the faster way to compute the result. As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048188/how-to-use-awk-sort-by-column-3).

Answer (score 27):

With `awk` you have to store the values in an array and compute the median at the end, assuming we look at the first column:

```
sort -n file | awk ' { a[i++]=$1; } END { print a[int(i/2)]; }'
```

Sure, for real median computation do the rounding as described in the question:

```
sort -n file | awk ' { a[i++]=$1; }
    END { x=int((i+1)/2); if (x < (i+1)/2) print (a[x-1]+a[x])/2; else print a[x-1]; }'
```

Answer (score 5):

OK, just saw this topic and thought I could add my two cents, since I looked for something similar in the past. Even though the title says `awk`, all the answers make use of `sort` as well. Calculating the median for a column of data can be easily accomplished with [datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
> seq 10 | datamash median 1
5.5
```

Note that `sort` is not needed, even if you have an unsorted column:

```
> seq 10 | gshuf | datamash median 1
5.5
```

The documentation gives all the functions it can perform, and good examples as well for files with many columns. Anyway, it has nothing to do with `awk`, but I think `datamash` is of great help in cases like this, and could also be used in conjunction with `awk`. Hope it helps somebody!

Answer (score 2):

[This AWK based answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13779/22734) to a similar question on unix.stackexchange.com gives the same results as Excel for calculating the median.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array to compute median from (contains one-liner of Johnsyweb solution):

```
array=(5 6 4 2 7 9 3 1 8) # numbers 1-9
IFS=$'\n'
median=$(awk '{arr[NR]=$1} END {if (NR%2==1) print arr[(NR+1)/2]; else print (arr[NR/2]+arr[NR/2+1])/2}' <<< sort <<< "${array[*]}")
unset IFS
```