# How to use awk sort by column 3

Tags: awk

I have a file (user.csv)like this

```
ip,hostname,user,group,encryption,aduser,adattr
```

want to print all column sort by user,

I tried `awk -F ":" '{print|"$3 sort -n"}' user.csv` , it doesn't work.

Comment: `sort -t, -k3 file`

Answer (score 246):

How about just `sort`.

```
sort -t, -nk3 user.csv
```

where

- `-t,` - defines your delimiter as `,`.
- `-n` - gives you numerical sort. Added since you added it in your
  attempt. If your user field is text only then you dont need it.
- `-k3` - defines the field (key). user is the third field.

Comment: How can I use sort 2 columns? for example, I want sort by column 6 first, and sort by column 3 second.

Comment: This won't work if there are quoted strings containing commas in the CSV (unless the column you want to sort by is earlier than the comma-containing column). You might have to make a pass first with awk (using FPAT="[^,]*|\"[^\"]*\"" and OFS="|" or some other delimiter that you could use with sort)

Comment: @user2452340 You could do this: `sort -t, -nk3 filename.csv | sort -t, -nk6` - first it will sort by column 3, then will sort that by column 6 so column 6 is sorted correctly all the way and for any rows where column 6 is the same, those will be sorted by column 3.

Comment: @Matthew `sort -t ',' -k3,3n -k6,6n` will be better. `-k3` will use column 3 and the rest of the line.

Comment: I just needed the -t, to divide my 2 column file divided by commas, thanks jaypal

Comment: I've compared performance and `sort -nk3` is considerably faster than `awk '{print $0|"sort -nk3 "}' ` (14 seconds compared with 66 seconds for a file with 1 million rows and 3 columns).

Answer (score 28):

1. Use awk to put the user ID in front.
2. Sort
3. Use sed to remove the duplicate user ID, assuming user IDs do not contain any spaces.

   ```
   awk -F, '{ print $3, $0 }' user.csv | sort | sed 's/^.* //'
   ```

Comment: This is very useful, especially if you need to parse or combine columns to add a sort field, then retain only the original line. I used awk/split to parse/combine date & time fields for a sort, then remove.

Comment: `sort` already knows how to sort by a particular column, but this technique -- known as the [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) -- is useful when the field you want to sort on is not trivially a well-defined column.

Comment: Would the `print $3, $0` print the sorted columns, or would it print the before-sorting columns?

Answer (score 17):

Seeing as that the original question was on how to use `awk` and every single one of the first 7 answers use `sort` instead, and that this is the top hit on Google, here is how to use `awk`.

Sample net.csv file with headers:

```
ip,hostname,user,group,encryption,aduser,adattr
192.168.0.1,gw,router,router,-,-,-
192.168.0.2,server,admin,admin,-,-,-
192.168.0.3,ws-03,user,user,-,-,-
192.168.0.4,ws-04,user,user,-,-,-
```

And `sort.awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S awk -f
#
# original source:
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/65768883/586229
#
# Usage:
#   awk -f sort.awk [-F<field separator>] [-v h=HAS_HEADER] [-v f=COLUMN_TO_SORT_BY] INPUT_FILE
# Examples:
#   awk -f sort.awk -F, -v h=1 -v f=1 input.csv > output.csv
#   cat input.txt | awk -f sort.awk | tee -a output.txt

# for each line
{
    if (h && NR == 0) {
        print $0
    } else {
        a[NR-h]=$0 ""
        s[NR-h]=$f ""
    }
}

END {
    isort(s, a, NR-h);
    for (i = 1; i <= NR-h; i++) {
        print a[i]
    }
}

# insertion sort of A[1..n]
function isort(S, A, n, i, j) {
    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        hs = S[j=i]
        ha = A[j=i]
        while (S[j-1] > hs) {
            j--;
            S[j+1] = S[j]
            A[j+1] = A[j]
        }
        S[j] = hs
        A[j] = ha
    }
}
```

To use it: 
See header in the script.

Comment: Thanks for actually answering the users question...

Answer (score 12):

You can choose a delimiter, in this case I chose a colon and printed the column number one, sorting by alphabetical order:

```
awk -F\: '{print $1|"sort -u"}' /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 10):

```
awk -F, '{ print $3, $0 }' user.csv | sort -nk2
```

and for reverse order

```
awk -F, '{ print $3, $0 }' user.csv | sort -nrk2
```

Answer (score 6):

try this -

```
awk '{print $0|"sort -t',' -nk3 "}' user.csv
```

OR

```
sort -t',' -nk3 user.csv
```

Comment: Is the `|` to `sort` using a built-in to `awk`?  If not, any idea why `-V` - `version sort` - would not work here?  Also, if I choose not to use `-t` option, it seems that to select the third column, I need to use `-k4` - odd indeed!

Answer (score 4):

```
awk -F "," '{print $0}' user.csv | sort -nk3 -t ','
```

This should work

Answer (score 3):

To exclude the first line (header) from sorting, I split it out into two buffers.

```
df | awk 'BEGIN{header=""; $body=""} { if(NR==1){header=$0}else{body=body"\n"$0}} END{print header; print body|"sort -nk3"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

With **GNU** `awk`:

```
awk -F ',' '{ a[$3]=$0 } END{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"; for(i in a) print a[i] }' file
```

See [8.1.6 Using Predefined Array Scanning Orders with gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) for more sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Linux (Ubuntu) with mawk:

```
tmp$ awk -W version
mawk 1.3.4 20200120
Copyright 2008-2019,2020, Thomas E. Dickey
Copyright 1991-1996,2014, Michael D. Brennan

random-funcs:       srandom/random
regex-funcs:        internal
compiled limits:
sprintf buffer      8192
maximum-integer     2147483647
```

mawk (and [gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html#index-_007c-_0028vertical-bar_0029-3)) has an option to redirect the output of `print` to a command. From `man awk` chapter *9. Input and output*:

> The output of print and printf can be redirected to a file or command by appending > file, >> file or | command to the end of the print statement.  Redirection opens file or command only once, subsequent redirections append to the already open stream.

Below you'll find a simplied example how `|` can be used to pass the wanted records to an external program that makes the hard work. This also nicely encapsulates everything in a single awk file and reduces the command line clutter:

```
tmp$ cat input.csv 
alpha,num
D,4
B,2
A,1
E,5
F,10
C,3
```

```
tmp$ cat sort.awk 
# print header line
/^alpha,num/ {
    print
}

# all other lines are data lines that should be sorted
!/^alpha,num/ {
    print | "sort --field-separator=, --key=2 --numeric-sort"
}
```

```
tmp$ awk -f sort.awk input.csv 
alpha,num
A,1
B,2
C,3
D,4
E,5
F,10
```

See `man sort` for the details of the `sort` options:

```
-t, --field-separator=SEP
       use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition
-k, --key=KEYDEF
       sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type
-n, --numeric-sort
       compare according to string numerical value
```

Comment: One can correctly argue this answer has no new information. However I found most of the other answers unnecessary terse and I had to dig out the magic of `|` from the mighty manual. So I wrote a note to myself for the next time :)