# Extract unique data from a large dataset

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a very large CSV dataset (900M records) that consists of the following format:

```
URL | IP | ActivityId
```

Sample data:

```
http://google.com/ | 127.0.0.1 | 2
http://google.com/ | 12.3.3.1 | 1
```

For this format, I wish to get all the unique activities per URL, that do not appear in other URLs.

For example, let's add one more sample to the data I provided above

```
http://yahoo.com/ | 123.4.5.1 | 2
```

Now ActivityId 2 is totally excluded because It belongs to two urls: Google and Yahoo. So what I want is to find all the activities that belong to a single URL only, and I wish to know the URL they belong to.

What I tried to do:

Create a dictionary

```
URL => set(activity1, activity2, ... , activityN)
```

(This part is slow, and was answered here [Parse a very large CSV dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43886157/parse-a-very-large-csv-dataset) )

With this dictionary, I compared each entry to eachother and found the difference between the sets and updated the corresponding set with the difference result.

How can I accomplish what I want using pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution with [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html):

```
df.groupby('ActivityId')['URL'].filter(lambda x: x.nunique() == 1)
```

And faster solution with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[df.groupby('ActivityId')['URL'].transform('nunique') == 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [21]: df.groupby('ActivityId')['URL'].filter(lambda x: len(x.unique()) == 1)
Out[21]:
1    http://google.com/
Name: URL, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in case you also want to know the ActivityID that belong to a single URL:

Imagine you have the following dataset:

```
    URL                 IP          ActivityId
0   http://google.com/  127.0.0.1   2
1   http://google.com/  12.3.3.1    1
2   http://yahoo.com/   123.4.5.1   2
3   http://yahoo.com/   123.4.5.1   5
```

You can do:

```
In[1]:groups = df.groupby('ActivityId')['URL']
      for name, group in groups:
          if group.size == 1:
              print (name,group.values[0])

Out[2]:1 http://google.com/ 
       5 http://yahoo.com/
```

Meanwhile using:

```
df.groupby('ActivityId')['URL'].filter(lambda x: len(x.unique()) == 1)
```

Yields:

```
1    http://google.com/ 
3     http://yahoo.com/ 
Name: URL, dtype: object
```