# sort variables by content bash and output variable name

Tags: bash, sorting, variables

I have some variables in a bash script

```
variable1=0.111
variable2=-222
variable3=0
variable4=0
```

....... and so on.

I know i can use `sort` to sort the variable content, but i want to know which is which after.
For example `echo $variable1 $variable2 $variable3 $variable4  | xargs -n1 |  sort -g` would do the tric, but it won't tell me which is which. I need the output to be like : `variable2, variable3, variable4 , variable1`. Is it possible? Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `sort`. Just make sure your echo has these values each on a separate line ([great answer on sorting by column here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17048248/9797143)), try this:

```
echo "variable1 $variable1
variable2 $variable2
variable3 $variable3
variable4 $variable4" | sort -t" " -nk2
```

From the above linked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17048248/9797143):

> -t, - defines your delimiter
>
> -n - gives you numerical sort
>
> -k2 - defines the field (key)