# Calculate median of a sliding window with awk

Tags: bash, awk, median, sliding-window

I need to produce a sliding window of millions of lines and to calculate the median of column 3. My data looks like this with column 1 always being the same, column 2 equaling the line number and column 3 being the information that I need the median for:

```
HiC_scaffold_1  1   34
HiC_scaffold_1  2   34
HiC_scaffold_1  3   36
HiC_scaffold_1  4   37
HiC_scaffold_1  5   38
HiC_scaffold_1  6   39
HiC_scaffold_1  7   40
HiC_scaffold_1  8   40
HiC_scaffold_1  9   40
HiC_scaffold_1  10  41
HiC_scaffold_1  11  41
HiC_scaffold_1  12  41
HiC_scaffold_1  13  44
HiC_scaffold_1  14  44
HiC_scaffold_1  15  55
```

and I need a result like this, assuming a sliding window of 4 and rounding to the nearest whole number. In the real dataset I'll likely use a sliding window of 1000:

```
HiC_scaffold_1  4   35
HiC_scaffold_1  5   37
HiC_scaffold_1  6   38
HiC_scaffold_1  7   39
HiC_scaffold_1  8   40
HiC_scaffold_1  9   40
HiC_scaffold_1  10  40
HiC_scaffold_1  11  41
HiC_scaffold_1  12  41
HiC_scaffold_1  13  41
HiC_scaffold_1  14  43
HiC_scaffold_1  15  44
```

I found the following script [here](https://shearnrylan.wordpress.com/2016/05/30/sliding-window-in-awk/) for doing what I want but for mean, not median:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" 'BEGIN {
        window = 4
        slide = 1
}

{
        mod = NR % window
        if (NR <= window) {
                count++
        } else {
                sum -= array[mod]
        }
        sum += $3
        array[mod] = $3
}

(NR % slide) == 0 {
        print $1, NR, sum / count
}
' file.txt
```

and this script for calculating median with awk from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49263254/3073294):

```
sort -n -k3 file.txt |
awk '{
        arr[NR] = $3
}

END {
        if (NR % 2 == 1) {
                print arr[(NR + 1) / 2]
        } else {
                print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" (arr[NR / 2] + arr[NR / 2 + 1]) / 2
        }
}
'
```

but I can't get them to work together. One other issue is that the median calculation requires a sorted input. I also found this [datamash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49263867/3073294) solution but I don't know how to make is work efficiently with a sliding window.

Comment: Why the second column shifted in the output? How is the fist and the last median calculated? Och, the first 3 lines are ignored?

Comment: datamash is great, but it doesn't have windows; all or nothing.

Comment: The output starts with line 4 because line 4 is the first line for which a sliding window of 4 can be produced. The last median is of the last line and the three lines previous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following assumes the availability of the function `asort`, as provided by GNU awk (gawk).  The program is parameterized by wsize, the window size -- here 4:

```
gawk -v wsize=4 '
   BEGIN { 
    if (wsize % 2 == 0) { m1=wsize/2; m2=m1+1; } else { m1 = m2 = (wsize+1)/2; } 
   }
   function roundedmedian() {
     asort(window, a);
     return (m1==m2) ? a[m1] : int(0.5 + ((a[m1] + a[m2]) / 2));
   }
   function push(value) {
     window[NR % wsize] = value;
   }
   NR < wsize { window[NR]=$3; next; }
   { push($3);
     $3 = roundedmedian();
     print $0;
   }'
```

Answer (score 5):

Using GNU awk for `asort()`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = "\t"
    window = 4
    befMid = int(window / 2)
    aftMid = befMid + (window % 2 ? 0 : 1)
}
{ array[NR % window] = $3 }
NR >= window {
    asort(array,vals)
    print $1, $2, int( (vals[befMid] + vals[aftMid]) / 2 + 0.5 )
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
HiC_scaffold_1  4       35
HiC_scaffold_1  5       37
HiC_scaffold_1  6       38
HiC_scaffold_1  7       39
HiC_scaffold_1  8       40
HiC_scaffold_1  9       40
HiC_scaffold_1  10      40
HiC_scaffold_1  11      41
HiC_scaffold_1  12      41
HiC_scaffold_1  13      41
HiC_scaffold_1  14      43
HiC_scaffold_1  15      44
```

Answer (score 4):

The following script with GNU awk seems to generate the output you presented:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' -v window=4 '
{
    # I store the numbers in an array `nums` indexed with `1 ... window`
    mod = NR % window + 1;
    nums[mod] = $3;
}

# If the count of numbers is greater or equal the window,
# we can start calculating the median.
NR >= window {

    # Copy the array nums, cause we need to sort it.
    for (i = 1; i <= window; ++i) {
        copy[i] = nums[i];
    }

    # Sort the copy.
    # asort is a GNU extension if I remember.
    # For non-gnu, write a sorting function yourself.
    asort(copy);

    # Calculate the median.
    # I hope that is ok.
    half = int( (window + 1) / 2 );
    if (window % 2 == 0) {
        # You seem to want to round 0.5 up.
        # Just add 1 and round down.
        median = int( (copy[half] + copy[half + 1] + 1) / 2 );
    } else {
        median = copy[half];
    }

    # Output
    print $1, $2, median 
}'
```